# Why does my Linux app get stopped every 0.5 seconds?

Tags: c, linux

I have a 16 core Linux machine that is idle. If I run a trivial, single threaded C program that sits in a loop reading the cycle counter forever (using the rdtsc instruction), then every 0.5 seconds, I see a 0.17 ms jump in the timer value. In other words, **every 0.5 seconds it seems that my application is stopped for 0.17ms.** I would like to understand why this happens and what I can do about it. I understand Linux is not a real time operating system. I'm just trying to understand what is going on, so I can make the best use of what Linux provides.

I found someone else's software for measuring this problem - https://github.com/nokia/clocktick_jumps. Its results are consistent with my own.

To answer the "tell us what specific problem you are trying to solve" question - I work on high-speed networking applications using DPDK. About 60 million packets arrive per second. I need to decide what size to make the RX buffers and have reasons that the number I pick is sensible. The answer to this question is one part of that puzzle.

My code looks like this:

```c
// Build with gcc -O2 -Wall
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <x86intrin.h>

int main() {
    // Bad way to learn frequency of cycle counter.
    unsigned long long t1 = __rdtsc();
    usleep(1000000);
    double millisecs_per_tick = 1e3 / (double)(__rdtsc() - t1);

    // Loop forever. Print message if any iteration takes unusually long.
    t1 = __rdtsc();
    while (1) {
        unsigned long long t2 = __rdtsc();
        double delta = t2 - t1;
        delta *= millisecs_per_tick;
        if (delta > 0.1) {
            printf("%4.2f - Delay of %.2f ms.\n", (double)t2 * millisecs_per_tick, delta);
        }
        t1 = t2;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm running on Ubuntu 16.04, amd64. My processor is an Intel Xeon X5672 @ 3.20GHz.

Comment: The scheduler pre-empts your app in favour of another app, then resumes your app.

Comment: Interestingly, I don't get the same behaviour, it does show a 0.1ms delay every now and then, but it's not consistent. It's probably got something to do with scheduling, so I added a `sched_getcpu` call to the printf, to see where I'm at, but now I never get any delays with -O2, might be it always migrates during that call, altough it's supposed to be fairly quick.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie 'I have a 16 core Linux machine that is idle' - doesn't seem likely that the OS would hold up one CPU-intensive thread at all.  Is it maybe some artifact of the rdtsc() driver?

Comment: I suppose it could be a thermal-management core migration, but 170us seems like a very long time indeed, even allowing for the inter-core comms interrupts/messages/whatever that would be required to stop the thread on one core and resume it on another.

Comment: @MartinJames, TSC is the Time Stamp Counter register and `__rdtsc` is an intrinisc to read the register. Seems there is no driver and we must conclude the app _is_ indeed suspended. As to why is another question.

Comment: Andrew, the app runs in user space and is subject to scheduling. Your receiver is an interrupt handling routine that is not subject to scheduling. It places received packets in a buffer shared with the user space app. If you run parallel apps in user space, you decrease the chance of no apps available to empty the buffer. Could that be a solution?

Comment: @Paul - My receiver is NOT an interrupt handling routine. DPDK bypasses the kernel, runs the NIC driver in user space, and polls the NIC hardware registers to see when packets arrive. However, multi-core might reduce the problem anyway but that gets complicated. I wanted to understand this _simple_ problem first :-)

Comment: Then there must be lots of unseen (kernel) processes running too, such as the thermal mnagement or system logging or whatever, and your app gets suspended. So your buffers must be large enough to handle the delay/suspension and your app/system must be fast enough for it.

Comment: @Paul - I think all the kernel processes show up in the output of `perf sched map` - my log is here https://pastebin.com/SQmBSpXK. I'm hoping there is a simple BIOS or kernel config change that makes the problem go away.

Comment: For 'kernel processes' to consistently preempt one thread on such a system would require 16 threads/processes to be ready at the same time, on a regular, timed basis.  That seems hugely unlikely:(

Comment: 60 million packets per second... that is 0.000000017 per packet.  That results in only a few CPU cycles per packet,  *I* think that the CPU cannot keep up with that rate.  BTW: how big are these packets?

Comment: @user3629249 In the case of 60 Mpps, the packets are 64 bytes (the minimum Ethernet frame size). It's standard practice to benchmark this case because it is so hard. There are results of DPDK achieving zero packet loss at 75 Mpps on 4 cores. See https://fast.dpdk.org/doc/perf/DPDK_18_02_Intel_NIC_performance_report.pdf. I'm not going to achieve results like that unless I can fix glitches like the one in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I expect your system is scheduling another process to run on the same CPU, and you're either replaced or moved to another core with some timing penalty.

You can find the reason by digging into kernel events happening at the same time. For example `systemtap`, or `perf` can give you some insight. I'd start with the scheduler events to eliminate that one first: https://github.com/jav/systemtap/blob/master/tapset/scheduler.stp

Comment: ''I have a 16 core Linux machine that is idle' - doesn't seem likely that the OP's box is so overloaded that one thread would get regularly preempted for 170us.  I would not expect it to get preempted at all.

Comment: Any tips on how to use scheduler.stp? I tried `stap -g scheduler.stp ./my_app` but got `semantic error: no probes found`.

Comment: I did `perf sched record ./my_app`, and left my app running for long enough to print 10 delay reports (5 seconds). The output of `perf sched map` is here: https://pastebin.com/SQmBSpXK.

Comment: @MartinJones Unless you pin an app to one logical CPU, they're often bouncing all over the place, even on mostly idle machines. I never dug into why that happens, but it's quite obvious from watching `htop`.

Comment: @viraptor Oh, I believe you!   Still, 170us seems a very long time for migration of such a simple program that can probably all fit into the L1 on each core:(

Comment: FWIW, htop shows my app running on the same core continuously.

Comment: @AndrewBainbridge (if I'm reading it correctly) From your file it looks like the only thing that preempts your process is the watchdog, but not at a 0.5s interval. You get migrated twice in the record. You can check if this was The reason by temporarily disabling the watchdog by writing 0 to /proc/sys/kernel/watchdog But it may be something different. Let us know if the watchdog turns out to not be the problem

Comment: I mean, what is there to do?  The core handling the timer interrupt has to interrupt the core running the rdtsc thread to make it enter the kernel, and interrupt a free core to get it out of halt.  Bit of fiddling around with state data and inter-core messages, and the rdtsc thread is off on its way on the new core...

Comment: @viraptor - No improvement with watchdog disabled. The perf sched map output is a little simpler: https://pastebin.com/xQ25j7jr. I'm beginning to think that the cause is some ring -1 thing, like remote admin features in the BIOS / Intel Management Engine. The machine is in a rack in a data center, where I have no physical access. Anyway, thanks for the help. At least I'm not missing something obvious. And I've learned about perf, htop, and disabling the watchdog, so it hasn't been a wasted morning.

Comment: @Martin - Indeed. 170us is 2500 cache misses and half a million clock cycles! Twice a second. I've written computer games that used less resource than that.